# Finding Database address and connecting to it through code

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I've just made a new SQL Database with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I'm trying to connect to it through some C# code. However, I'm having some issues doing so.

I'm trying to connect to my database with the following line:

```
  String DBConnection = "Data Source=unknown; Database=SQLExpress\\Darkride; Language=English";
```

However my program can't find my database as I have no idea where my data source is. I've been trying to find it for hours now, but I'm getting nothing.

Does anyone know where I can find out my databases Data Source?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with mysql (wrong tag) or the SQL management studion (wrong title).

Comment: '.\SQLEXPRESS' or 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS' or '127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on the connection string examples here http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Looks like it can be something like:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Darkride;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `Initial Catalog` in the connection string:

```
 String DBConnection ="Data Source='localhost';Integrated Security='SSPI' Initial Catalog=Darkride;";
```

check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`"Data Source=127.0.0.1; Database=SQLExpress\\Darkride;Initial Catalog=YourDataBase;User Id=user;Password=pass"`

You can use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to build your connection string.

A good site for refenrence is http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Have connection string format as:**

```
String DBConnection = "Data Source=27.0.0.1;;Initial Catalog=Darkride;User ID=userIDText;Password=PasswordText";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Darkride;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

And take a look on the link below

Connectionstring.com will help : [Connection strings for SQL Server 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Best Regards